# Calling External API with Requests keeps returning Error: could not handle the request

Tags: python, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a google cloud function in python which will just get some data from an API and display it:

```
from flask import escape
import requests
import json

def randomFact(request):
    URL = "https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en"
    r = requests.get(URL).json()
    return r
```

This is the requirement.txt:

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version

functions-framework==3.0.0
flask==2.0.2
flask-restful==0.3.9
requests==2.11.0
```

However every time I run it I just get a response saying: Error: could not handle the request.
I have enabled billing for the project so that is not the issue, and I have tested it locally and it works perfectly but it just doesn't work when I put it in a google cloud function.

Please help if you know any way to solve this issue or just how to call an external API from a google cloud function, I have been trying for 3 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue. If you look at the logs inside cloud functions, it says there's an ssl certificate error.

I tried changing your requirements.txt to not include a version number on `requests` and it worked:

```
functions-framework==3.0.0
requests
flask==2.0.2
flask-restful==0.3.9
```